# Translate MySQL query to BigQuery query

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

I am having trouble converting MySQL query to Google Bigquery query. This is my MySQL query

```
SELECT id
FROM office_details
GROUP BY address
HAVING max(value)
ORDER BY id
```

This query runs perfectly on phpMyAdmin and with my php script. But when I convert it to bigquery

```
SELECT id
FROM Office_db.office_details
GROUP BY address
HAVING max(value)
ORDER BY id
```

It says column `id` is not in group by nor aggregated.

What I need is the `id`s of unique `address` where `value` is maximum. e.g

```
+-------------------------+
| id  |  address |  value |
+-------------------------+
| 1   |    a     |   4    |
| 2   |    a     |   3    |
| 3   |    b     |   2    |
| 4   |    b     |   2    |
+-------------------------+
```

I need

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 1  |
| 3  |
+----+
```

Comment: The original query is nonsensical, so not sure what you want us to do.

Comment: there are multiple entries of same address in a table. I want to get `id` of just one address against whom the `value` is max for these `address` entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT id FROM (
  SELECT 
    id, address, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY address ORDER BY value DESC, id) AS flag
  FROM office_details
)
WHERE flag = 1
```

Comment: @Strawberry - not sure what you meant. As question asks - my answer is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Comment: Doh! I need more coffee!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(id ORDER BY value DESC, id LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS id
FROM office_details
GROUP BY address;
```

It's less prone to running out of memory than a solution using `RANK` will be (and may be faster), since it doesn't need to buffer all of the rows while computing ranks within a partition. As a working example:

```
#standardSQL
WITH office_details AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'a' AS address, 4 AS value UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'a', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'b', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'b', 2
)
SELECT
  address,
  ARRAY_AGG(id ORDER BY value DESC, id LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS id
FROM office_details
GROUP BY address
ORDER BY address;
```

This gives the result:

```
address | id
------------
a       | 1
b       | 3
```

Answer (score 0):

A valid query might look as follows:

```
SELECT MIN(x.id) id
  FROM office_details x
  JOIN
     ( SELECT address
            , MAX(value) value
         FROM officer_details
        GROUP 
           BY address
     ) y
    ON y.address = x.address
   AND y.value = x.value
 GROUP 
    BY address
     , value
```

Comment: with this query I might get more than 1 id of same address. because it is possible that value and address both are same in the table

Comment: @SSMA Amend your question to reflect this new information - and the result that you would want returned in that eventuality.

Comment: @SSMA Likewise.